# Ansible: Use of fetch action in my Python module

Tags: python, ansible-2.x

I try to implement new Ansible module in Python which includes 2 parts:

1. collect conf file from sensor gateway and put this file on remote host as a temp file
2. fetch action - get this file to local host (ansible server)

In the end of running Ansible delete all the temp files

I finish a first part and don't know how to implement fetch action.

I can do second part as a additional tasks (fetch module for copy file to local host + file module for deleting temp conf file from remote host) in the ansible playbook but i want to do all action in my module without any additional tasks.